# React-native Make image pop-up using lightbox

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, lightbox

When using react native lightbox, the image pops up in the left side of the screen, but with the same size as defined in the image component.

I want the image to pop up in the center of the screen with a bigger size than before.

Here is my code:

```
 return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Button
      title="Pick an image from camera roll"
      onPress={this._pickImage}
    />


    <Lightbox onPress={() => this.enlargeImage(image)} >
      {/*    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.enlargeImage(image)}> */}
      <Image
        source={{ uri: image }}
        style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
      />
      {/* </TouchableOpacity> */}
    </Lightbox>
```

When i press the image i want to return the image in new size in the center of the screen:

```
 enlargeImage = (image) => {
  return (
  <Lightbox>
    <Image
      source={{ uri: image }}
      style={{ width: 500, height: 500 }}
      resizeMode='center'
    />
  </Lightbox>
)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `renderContent` props of Lightbox ([docs](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox#properties)). And doing something like that:

```
<Lightbox renderContent={()=> {
  return(
    <Image
     source={require('./photo.png')}
     style={{ width: 1000, height: 1000 }}
     resizeMode='center'
    />
  )
}}>
 <Image
   source={require('./photo.png')}
   style={{ width: 500, height: 500 }}
   resizeMode='center'
 />
</Lightbox>
```

I hope this will help somebody.

Comment: thnks that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap the `Lightbox` into a `Button`.
When you then size the container around it instead of the lightbox.

```
<TouchableOpacity> style={{ margin: 5, width: width / 3 - 17, height: 110 }}
   <Lightbox>
       <Image
         source={{ uri: image }}
         style={{ width: 500, height: 500 }}
         resizeMode='center'
       />
   </Lightbox>
</TouchableOpacity>
```